# TokenMismatchException in Ajax post request in laravel with token passing

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm submitting form data with ajax and I'm getting this token mismatch error while still passing token. 
Here's  my code snippet:

```
var _csrfToken = $('meta[name=token]').attr('content');
var link = $('meta[name=url]').attr('content');


// $.ajaxSetup({
//     headers: {
//         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
//     }
// });

$('#upload_form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var designation = $('#position').val();
    var category = $('#category').val();
    var azimaData = {
        name: title,
        designation: designation,
        category: category,
         _token: _csrfToken
    };

    console.log(azimaData);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: link + '/@dashboard@/galleryImage/add_image',
        data: azimaData,
        //use contentType, processData for sure.
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(msg) {

            if(msg.status == success)
            {
                alert(msg.msg);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(msg.msg);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {

            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });

});
```

Other Ajax requests are working fine with the token issue. Where did I go wrong with this one?

Comment: Is this is one script tag? Or is it loaded into another function?

Comment: @mbozwood this is one script tag.

Comment: humour me, if this is in blade, change your _token in the data to `_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'`. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send data in an object form, while after setting the contentType and processData options to false. So in this scenario, you can send the data either by serializing the form or by creating a new FormData instance and appending the data to it manually.

I have edited your code. And have used FormData for sending the data along with the token.

```
    $('#upload_form').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var designation = $('#position').val();
        var category = $('#category').val();
        var azimaData = new FormData(); // create a new FormData.. 
        azimaData.append('name', title);
        azimaData.append('designation', designation);
        azimaData.append('category', category);
        azimaData.append('_token', _csrfToken);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: link + '/@dashboard@/galleryImage/add_image',
            data: azimaData,
            //use contentType, processData for sure.
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function(msg) {

                if(msg.status == success)
                {
                    alert(msg.msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(msg.msg);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {

                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the ajax request by removing `contentType: false` and `processData:false` from your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: link + '/@dashboard@/galleryImage/add_image',
    data: azimaData,
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.status == success) {
            alert(msg.msg);
        } else {
            alert(msg.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

[jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Azima Could you update what `console.log(azimaData);` looks like?

Comment: Object {name: "Katell Wilcox", designation: "Inventore sed dolorum expedita ut maxime adipisicing aut voluptatibus aperiam obcaecati vitae", category: "7", _token: "69LPiaHojmwnaFdK1nRtW04Y2yCZl1G3MAgGfJtJ"}
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/@dashboard@/galleryImage/add_image 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ admin.js:27
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
jquery.min.js:2 Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType:

Comment: sorry i didn't know how to comment images

Comment: and are you getting `tokenMismatch` Exception as a response?

Comment: yes.. i've checked token multiple times... token is the same when viewing in console and when printing in view file

Comment: Is the route within the web middleware group?

Answer (score -1):

Change your `meta name`. It should be something like this

```
var _csrfToken = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
```

Comment: It doesnt matter what name the meta token has. Aslong as you reference it, it can be whatever. I use `csrf-token` in all mine

Comment: are you get all data in your `console.log(azimaData);`

Comment: @ArigiWiratama no.. it is throwing token mismatch exception

Comment: I don't know, I think we have to debug it first :(. Okay are you sure you set your meta content with `{{ csrf_token() }}`

Comment: @ArigiWiratama yes.. it is working with other ajax requests

Comment: Wooow that's amazing, maybe you can add the solution with updating your question :-D